# Obtaining Academic Work Permit in Europe/USA

Tags: united-states, job-search, europe

What is the process of obtaining a work permit (to work in Academia) in US and Europe? I have noticed on many job postings there is a question along the lines of "are you authorized to work in Europe" (or US).

If one is offered a position, then I assume the university arranges the work permit. But my question is focused on getting the work permit in advance to increase chances of getting an interview.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In most European countries, you cannot obtain a work permit without a work offer, so you cannot really obtain this in advance. The work permit is evaluated according to the work offer you obtain, so everything depends on that.

Comment: I have worked at a German university's English department for twenty years and have hired academic personnel below professorial level: a work permit has never been a prerequisite. Actually, the university has acted as though getting the work permit was solely the applicants responsibility. It has always worked like this: person (e.g. from Africa) applied, was selected to get the contract, then approached the state's foreigners' office with the work offer to get a permit, then was given the contract. It is sometimes tedious (e.g. from African states), but has always worked in my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the US at least, you need a position before getting a visa.

If a posting mentions needing to be allowed to work in the US, they're probably talking about a contingency, not a prerequisite: if you fail to get a visa after being offered a position, the offer sensibly becomes void. If there is some legal reason you cannot get a visa, you shouldn't even bother applying, but otherwise it certainly isn't expected nor possible that you have prior authorization.

If a question is asked about whether you are authorized to work in a country when you apply, you should answer honestly; this is not necessarily used to deny you a job, it's likely they need to know if you don't have authorization **so that they can help you get it**.